# PynamoDB query() returns 0 values while scan() does

Tags: python, dynamodb-queries, pynamodb

I have declared a pretty basic model and testing out query and other functionalities.
I can run `scan()` and get all of the objects from dynamoDB, but when I run `query` I don't get back anything.
I looked at examples, documentations and searched on internet. Couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my model:

```py
class Book(BaseModel):
    id = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True, null=False, default_for_new=uuid.uuid4())
    name = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)
    author = UnicodeAttribute(null=True)
    pages = NumberAttribute(null=True)

    class Meta:
        table_name = BOOKS_TABLE_NAME
```

Here is the code that I have written as sample:

```py
# List all books - Passes
print('Fetching all books')
books = Book.scan()
for b in books:
    print(b.id)
    print(b.name)
    # Fetch single book - Failed
    print('Fetching single book')
    book = list(Book.query(b.id))
    print(book)
```

If I use `boto3` to get the item I am able to fetch it.

```py
book = dynamodb_client.get_item(
    TableName=BOOKS_TABLE_NAME,
    Key={
        'id': {
            'S': id
        },
    }
)
print(book)
```

I am not sure why accessing via `boto3` is working but not via pynamoDB.
Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: same issue at my side
getting answer from boto3, but pynamodb query on partition key is not working

Comment: Have you tried casting the value of `default_for_new` from UUID to a string? I wasn't able to repro this issue since using `uuid.uuid4()` as the default value gives an error on save: `TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable`. Everything works as expected when the uuid is cast to a string. If the issue persists, please add any additional setup that might be useful to reproduce the issue, including how the db is populated.